# Pushing file to web-browser while being written

Tags: php, python, linux, file-io, ffmpeg

I have a backgrounded ffmpeg process which is outputting a audio file, I want to push this file to user web-browser while ffmpeg continues to write upon the file. I tried the below but this send 0 byte files.

```
// open the file in a binary mode
$fp = fopen($fname, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fname));
ob_end_clean();
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

ffmpeg cannot be launched from PHP/Python and output captured here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fpassthru` function won't do the job here.  In addition, there is going to be an issue of knowing when the file is complete.

File reading functions stop when the end of the file is reached.  If there is a concurrent writer increasing the length of the file, then it's indeterminate how far along a reader will get before seeing EOF.  In addition, there's no clear way - through the file operations - to know whether the file writer is done.

It may be feasible to attempt to read with timeouts using a loop like this (psuedo-code):

```
LOOP
    READ bytes
    IF count read == 0
    THEN
        SLEEP briefly
        INCREMENT idle_count
    ELSE
        SET idle_count = 0
        WRITE
    END IF
UNTIL ( idle_count == 10 )
```

I can put that into PHP code if it helps.

Here is PHP code that does this with two files, `in.dat` and `out.dat`:

```
<?php

$in_fp = fopen("./in.dat", "r");

$out_fp = fopen("./out.dat", "w");

$idle_count = 0;

while ( $idle_count < 10 )
{
    if ( $idle_count > 0 )
        sleep(1);

    $val = fread($in_fp, 4192);
    if ( ! $val )
    {
        $idle_count++;
    }
    else
    {
        $idle_count = 0;
        $rc = fwrite($out_fp, $val);
        if ( $rc != strlen($val) )
            die("error on writing of the output file\n");
    }
}
```

Note the odd location of the sleep is to prevent sleeping one second after the last attempt to read.

I recommend setting the idle timeout limit higher than 10 for this purpose.

Comment: The ffmpeg process is outputting files sizing 3-10MB's so I guess the solution you suggested should work. Can you pls. provide a plug-n-play example for me to try, thanks. Edit : One more thing, this will read the file but dont push it to user in real-time, right ?

Comment: It pushes in real-time.  The psuedo-code didn't mention the write; my bad.  I'll put it in there.

Comment: The value of pushing the file real-time is clear to me.  Both the ffmpeg and push of the file are long-running processes, so better to do both in parallel.  Wish there were a more definitive way to know ffmpeg is done in a generic way.  If you can modify the ffmpeg process (e.g. add more commands to a script that calls ffmpeg), then a marker file would be a good way to go.  Then you can eliminate the idle check and instead add a "check-if-marker-file-exists" in it's place.

Comment: Here's the situation - [ffmpeg command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654365/pushing-data-to-web-browser-while-processing-input-from-ffmpeg/18655322), the only reason I need the above asked solution (which I have a strong feeling is the wrong way to tackle this) is to somehow verify that the input file is not zero byte resulted due to error from upstream wget(in quite mode) command.

Comment: Interesting - I don't see how that fits into the PHP since there is no zero-byte-size check there.  If that's the case, a flag-file may be the best way to notify the PHP script that the ffmpeg processing is complete.

Comment: I am now doing another check for 0 byte data using curl before executing the piped wget and ffmpeg.